# SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'contact' at row 1

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Bsv.png)

I have an issue in this code the error is

> SQL State [22003] Numeric value out of range for column contact

Can anyone please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Please insert the code instead of pictures. What is your contact type in the database?

Comment: can I see your migration file of your model you are willing to insert data ?

Comment: Hi Hamza, in SQL the max number int can hold is 4294967295 (unsigned), If you want an even bigger number try using BIG INT which can go upto 184467440737
09551615. But as a standard i would recommend to keep Contact info as String as it wont be changing once fed and no mathematical computations is done on contact.
If in any case you need to do mathematical computation just change it to string using your programming language.

Comment: Its integer type in table I create Firdaus Nasir

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is with numeric type. It is 32 bit long which can accomodate as much as 10^9 value. You are willing to insert 11 digits minimum. There is a problem. You can use string or higher range of muneric value(BIG INT).

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what your error message states. The value you're trying to insert in your contact column is bigger than it's range. Usually the `int` type takes a width of up to 11 digits. For keeping contact numbers use `varchar`. Because, it enables a user to insert dashes or spaces.